# Object Embed not working with Node Express routes

Tags: flash, node.js, routes, express

I have the following code in my index.jade file

```
        object(type="application/x-shockwave-flash", data="VideoIO.swf", id="video1")
    param(name="movie", value="VideoIO.swf")
    param(name="quality",value="high")
    param(name="bgcolor",value="#000000")
    param(name="allowScriptAccess",value="always")
    param(name="flashVars", value="controls=true")
```

In my express application I have set up my routes like

```
    app.get('/',function(req,res){  
res.render('index.jade',{title:'Express'});

    })
```

This works fine but when I add this route :

```
    app.get('/:username',function(req,res){
The Flash swf file does not load.
  })
```

What might be the problem here ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is when you've edited the actual code out of your second apt.get example. Do you have a render in that second example? Is it still trying to render index.jade? Are you not seeing what's expected when doing a get on `/username` or is the original `/` route broken too?

Comment: Even if i leave it blank and just write res.end() the swf file was not loading ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround ..

I defined a separate route for the swf file I wanted to embed like this

```
    app.get('/services/loadSwf',function(req,res){
         res.render('jade_file_containing_objectembed_code',{title:'hello'})


    })
```

Now I load that swf file into my main application using iframes by setting the "src" property of the iframe to 'services/loadSwf' and it works fine.